# AutoMapper from KeyValuePair elements to entity

Tags: c#, automapper

I have `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` with 2 elemets. 
1) Key = AgregateOn
   Value = Amount/Weight/Quantity

2) Key = Max/Min
   Value = decimal value(Amount/Weight) or int (Quantity)

//i have interface

```
public interface IQuantityRestriction
{
    int? MinQuantity { get; set; }
    int? MaxQuantity { get; set; }
    decimal? MinAmount { get; set; }
    decimal? MaxAmount { get; set; }
    decimal? MinWeight { get; set; }
    decimal? MaxWeight { get; set; }
}
```

So how i can map it from this `ConfigurationData(KeyValuePair List)`  to `IQuantityRestriction` with AutoMapper`?
for example 
<AgregateOn,Quantity> , <Max,5>` should be mapped to `IQuantityRestriction` with property MaxQuantity = 5. Is it possible ?

Comment: Its unclear what you want to map to this interface. Please give sample of data. But from first glance it looks like manual mapping will be easier

Comment: For example 
var configurationData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                        {
                         new KeyValuePair<string, string>                                       ("AggregateOn", "Quantity"),
                         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Max", "5")
                                        };

So i want map this configurationData to IQuantityRestriction with property MaxQuantity = 5.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there will be some benefit of Automapper usage. It cannot guess that something should be mapped by value from first item in list together with key from second item, and value from second item should be parsed to decimal. You can do all this stuff only manually. E.g. with Automapper mapping configuration will look like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, QuantityRestriction>()
        .AfterMap((src, qr) =>
        {
            switch (src[0].Value)
            {
                case "Quantity":
                    switch (src[1].Key)
                    {
                        case "Max":
                            qr.MaxQuantity = Int32.Parse(src[1].Value);
                            break;
                        case "Min":
                            qr.MinQuantity = Int32.Parse(src[1].Value);
                            break;
                    }
                    return;
                // case "Amount"
                // case "Weight"
            }
        });
```

Which is not any better than mapping without Automapper.